# What is a sticky footer in Muse?

Tags: adobe-muse

I'm just learning Adobe Muse and setting up a website with this tool.

What does "Sticky Footer" mean? What does it do, exactly?

Comment: Is the [description in the official Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/muse/using/creating-headers-footers.html#UsingStickyFooters) unclear in any way? It seems to me it covers the basics.

Comment: Thank you for posting the link. 

I was looking at the page for creating a new site, which mentions the sticky footer but didn't actually explain it.